# React component is not re-rendering multiple time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an application in which i have a button which change the theme from dark to light of the component. my application works fine for the first time but it does not work on second attempt

for example : If i click the button first time then it will change the theme to the dark mode but when i want to change the theme into light mode then it does not work

```
import {
Button,
createMuiTheme,
Grid,
Paper,
Switch,
ThemeProvider,
Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Mode extends Component { 


  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  switch: false,
};
this.darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
  },
});
this.lightTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light",
  },
});
}
    componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log(this.state.switch);
}
render() {
  return (
   <div>
     <ThemeProvider
      theme={this.state.switch === true ? this.darkTheme : this.lightTheme}
    > // <-- **Condition for changing the mode**
      <Paper style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <Grid container direction="column">
          <Typography variant="h1">this is my app</Typography>

          <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
            A button
          </Button>
          <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
            Another button
          </Button>
          <Switch
            checked={this.state.switch}
            onChange={() =>
              this.setState((prev) => ({ switch: !prev.switch }))
            }
            name="Dark Mode"
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
  );
   }
   }
```

I am using material ui for this

Comment: Your code is incorect (closing bracket before `componentDidUpdate`), hope it's a ctrl+c ctrl+v mistake..

Comment: And what about this console log, does it show the correct state changes?

Comment: yes it show @k-wasilewski yes its a copy paste mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it changes only one time. But you can fix by create `theme` every render.

First, create function `createTheme`:

```
const createTheme = (isDark) =>
  createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: isDark ? "dark" : "light",
    },
  });
```

Then, update `ThemeProvider` like this:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={createTheme(this.state.switch)}>
```

Comment: done  appreciate thanks,  make an update of your solution. "<ThemeProvider theme={this.createTheme(this.state.switch)}> 
" use this keyword with the function call soo if the beginner see the solution they don't frustrate